# Is it safe to replace MySQL to Percona Server with XtraDB on Debian Lenny?

Tags: mysql, debian, lenny, percona

I would like to replace MySQL 5.1 on my Debian Lenny 32-bit server to Percona Server with XtraDB. The main reason is better performance of Percona.

It's production server with many services running. Many other software may depend on mysql-client and other mysql shared libraries.

Is it safe to replace MySQL?

By "safe" I mean: 1. remove mysql, 2. install percona 3. everything works as before

Will it break dependencies in third party software? 
Will it require to change configuration of third party software (ie. socket path, server port, shared libraries path)?
Will it require to install trillion of additional packages?

I really don't want situation with broken libraries, missing or incompatible header files and so on

Comment: The obvious breakage will be any applications you have written to interact with MySql. Otherwise, we don't know what software you have, so we would not know what will be broken. ;)

Comment: @IAbstract: Percona claims to be "Drop-in Replacement for Standard InnoDB". So I expect to replace mysql with it and everything should work exactly as before and it should be client-software agnostic

Comment: How is it was? Have you installed in a such way? What problems and what information you can add to this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are currently in the process of upgrading from MySQL 4.1 to Percona Server 5.5 at work and Percona is as they say on their site a complete drop-in replacement for MySQL, the binaries use the same names, it uses the same libraries, same config file placement, takes the same parameters and it has exactly the same SQL syntax. They should also be data file compatible on the same version (MySQL 5.1 to Percona 5.1, etc) but it's nothing I've personally verified.

You are able to do an apt-get install percona-server-server-5.1 after adding their repositiories and it will automatically replace MySQL because it marks it as a conflicting package. But you must take an SQL dump of your database first, of course.

We currently have replication set up from a MySQL 4.1 master to a couple of Percona 5.5 slaves and have had no problems inserting SQL dumps either.

Answer (score 0):

... don't know.

In my experience, the only way is to make up a copy of your existing setup on an old machine and run some tests. Then swap over to the new DB and run same tests again.

I just swapped a set of applications from Tomcat 5  to Tomcat 6 and in theory, with one or two tweaks, all should have worked fine. First time I tried it OpenJava was installed and the garbage collection fouled things up. Second time around with Sun Java, some dodgy date handling fouled things up and had to be corrected, seems to run fine now.